# Console application not starting processes when scheduled in Windows

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple .NET console app in C#, that runs an external process "pscp" (putty secure copy). This works great when I just run the .exe.

However, when I schedule the application in windows scheduled tasks, the application does not seem to open the external process pscp.exe. Normally it should pop up an extra console screen and open pscp.exe there. This works, just not when scheduled.

I start the process like this:

```
pscp.FileName = "pscp.exe";
Process p = Process.Start(pscp);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check the properties of p, that should shed some light on the issue. Or maybe your console app doesn't run under an account that can start pscp.exe...

Comment: Is this the full example? Is pscp on your PATH? If this is part of putty then you will also need to supply some arguments, pscp.exe without any will just print a usage  message and exit.

Comment: no this is not the full example. I have arguments in the full code and the path to the pscp.exe has been set in a .config file

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled for your app? Add the code that opens pscp.exe in a try/catch block and log the resulting exception (if any). I've had unexpected behavior with scheduled tasks and logging really helped out.

Comment: it says "cannot find the file specified" so I guess the pscp.exe cannot be found. How can I add it to the PATH?

Comment: IanNorton, your answer is the correct one. Can I mark it as a correct answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Starting cmd with the /c argument runs "your exe" in a new cmd window.

Comment: where should I run this? I'm scheduling the c# .exe in scheduled tasks. In the source code itself, I call the external .exe with the code written above in my question. I'm not calling cmd?

Comment: run cmd /c /Path/to/PscP/pscp.exe in your application using the Process class.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled task runs under a different identity. Make sure that's working. Also, make sure you wrap the call to your exe with a cmd /c "your exe".

Comment: not sure what you mean by cmd /c "your exe". Can you clear this up for me? Thanks for helping out!