# Process.Start() fails to execute when run as Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, .net, windows, server, scheduled-tasks

I have a .NET console application written in C# (myApp.exe), that runs an external application ('bob.exe'). The console application works great when I run myApp.exe manually. The C# code that calls the application is:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\\bob.exe");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Create the process and assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
```

In Windows Server 2003, I created a Scheduled Task that executed 'myApp.exe' on a regular basis. It was set to execute even if the user was not logged in. The Scheduled Task worked and called 'bob.exe' (I was able to verify this by viewing the output files from 'bob.exe')

We then upgraded to Windows Server 2012. I created a Scheduled Task in Windows Server 2012, setting it to execute even if the user was not logged in and configuring it for Windows Server 2003.

I set the Action to call 'C:\myApp.exe', similar to how I had it set up in Windows Server 2003

When the scheduled tasks executes and I am logged in, the 'bob.exe' application is executed from 'myApp.exe'. However, when I am not logged in and the scheduled task executes, 'myApp.exe' is executed but 'bob.exe' is never executed (I can verify this by seeing there are no output files from 'bob.exe'). There are no errors reported by the Scheduled Task and the Last Run Result says "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)".

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787015/console-application-not-starting-processes-when-scheduled-in-windows) but I was unable to resolve my situation. What am I missing?

Comment: And the error message?

Comment: There are no error messages returned/reported by the Scheduled Task. The Last Run Result says "The operation completed successfully".

Comment: Add error logging. You need to do that anyway. Give us the exception ToString output. It also could be the case that bob.exe started successfully and crashed soon after.

Comment: @usr The application 'bob.exe' that is launched from proc.Start() is an external third party application. Since I launch 'bob.exe' as a separate process, the original application ('myApp.exe') does not have access to any exceptions thrown. To note - my entire function that runs the external application is wrapped in a try/catch. There are no exceptions thrown/caught.

The title of this question is slightly mis-leading. There is no failure in the Process.Start(). It appears to just not execute when the application is run as a Scheduled Task and the user is not logged in.

Comment: Then your best hope to debug this is to capture console output of bob and attach a process monitor trace. There'll be some access violation or an unexpected path being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my app calling out 7za.exe to archive db backups. When I ran my app manually it worked fine, but when I scheduled my app via Task Scheduler, the 7z routine would not fire off and didn't give my app a verbose error. I found that adding the directory I ran my app from to the task scheduler's Start in (optional): box corrected my issue.

**Program/script:** "C:\Program Files (x86)\CustApp\CustApp.exe"

**Start in (optional)** C:\Program Files (x86)\CustApp\

Note not to use double-quotes on the "Start in (optional)" setting for the directory, it errors when I did.

Comment: I tried this on Win Server 2016 and it worked. User was already defined with which it has to execute the task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with running a Batch file (on WS2008) and the problem was due to the permissions given to the user executing the scheduled task on the folders where the Batch file and the Executable files were set.
I'm not sure if the security of WS 2012 is different, but if I were You I'll try to debug the application (if you have the code) checking for permissions.
HTH

Comment: The scheduled task is set to execute using the same username/account when it works (i.e., when I am logged in and the schedule task runs automatically) and when it does not work (i.e., when I am not logged in and the scheduled task runs automatically). Would permissions be an issue with this set up?

Comment: I think Someone with more experience as a System Administrator will be able to answer you better, what I can say is that A scheduled task that worked for years in our system stopped working a couple of weeks ago, and we didn't change the permission of the user running it both on the executable and batch files and the folders to which the user had access. Even in our case, the Job did not give any error message, but the tasks were not executed, I think you need to check on the security policies for the user and to see if when working as a "service" account its permissions are somehow changed.